# Remove outliers from line graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, outliers

I want to draw a line graph where there is a clear outlier. The following dataset is a subset of the one I'm using:

```
          Date PCROI
717 2014-06-28    38
718 2014-06-29    41
719 2014-06-30    36
720 2014-07-01   734
721 2014-07-02    60
722 2014-07-03    78
723 2014-07-04    90
724 2014-07-05    68
725 2014-07-06    55
726 2014-07-07    57
```

If I plot this using `ggplot2` the graph is not that bad..

```
ggplot(data = example, aes(x = Date, y = PCROI)) + geom_line()
```

[image: Plot]

Unfortunately the time series I'm working with is much longer than the median of PCROI is 51. 
How can I adapt the chart without excluding the value from the dataset?

Comment: Have you tried putting the y-axis on a log scale?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `subset` command if you have some criteria for outliers (e.g., if PRCOI is greater than 100) and if you're fine with interpolating the deleted point:

```
example <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "          Date PCROI
717 2014-06-28    38
718 2014-06-29    41
719 2014-06-30    36
720 2014-07-01   734
721 2014-07-02    60
722 2014-07-03    78
723 2014-07-04    90
724 2014-07-05    68
725 2014-07-06    55
726 2014-07-07    57")
example$Date <- as.Date(example$Date)

ggplot(subset(example, PCROI <= 100), aes(Date, PCROI)) + geom_line()
```